# why can a defect have a lower barrier strength compared with another defect but still have a larger effect on embrittlement?

Tags: physical-properties-of-materials

I have read that for a particular alloy system, a specific precipitate has a low barrier strength to plastic deformation in comparison to dislocation loops. However this precipitate gives the largest contribution to embrittlement. How could this be?

Comment: Let us know if you want this migrated to Engineering.SE.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @NikeDattani That would help yes please